# How to dynamically assign _data variable?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm using staticman to enable comments on my blog. It puts the comments in the `_data` folder. My folder structure then looks like this:

```
_data/
    comments/
        blog-post-1/
            entry1542891129928.yml
            ...
        blog-post-2/
            entry1542891129928.yml
            ...
        ...
```

In my `_layouts/post.html` I want to access comments for a specific blog. This is the code that I expect to work to get to the comments:

```
{% assign comments = site.data.comments[page.slug] | sort %}
```

But when I run build, I get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 39): Cannot sort a null object. in /_layouts/post.html
```

It seems to be something to do with `page.slug` because if I replace it with the string 'blog-post-1' it works.

How to get the post slug dynamically in post.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved the problem!

The issue is when the folder does not exist. I circumvent this by moving the sort filter:

```
{% assign comments = site.data.comments[page.slug] %}
{% if comments %}
    {% assign comments = comments | sort %}
    ...do things...
{% endif %}
```

Now the build doesn't fail.